# How can I change from IPv6 to IPv4 when connecting to VNC server?

Tags: vnc, ipv6

I am taking a mechatronics class in college and am using a Raspberry Pi 4. It was working fine till last week but this week it wont connect to the vnc server.

I am able to enter the `ping raspberrypi.local` to get the address and then connect using `ssh pi@address`.

However, once I try to connect to the VNC server it does not allow me, stating invalid endpoint. I have noticed that it shows the VNC server address as IPv6 (inet6) instead of IPv4 like last time when it worked.

So I am wondering if there was a way to change the server address from IPv6 to IPv4, or if there are any other ways of fixing this problem?

The VNC viewer I'm using is Real VNC (enter image description here https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: put a space before and after a URL

Comment: None of networking devices have an IPv4 address so this has nothing to do with VNC.

Comment: What are you filling in the URL field? Is it https://example.com or https://93.184.216.34 or https://[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946] ? The first uses DNS to lookup one of the other two (IPv4 & IPv6 respectively). It's nothing to do with VNC nor the Raspberry Pi. It's basic simple networking so doesn't belong here.